# Why my code isn't giving the correct substring in the string?

Tags: string, c++14, substr

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
bool RKalgorithm(string pat,string s){
    int patL=pat.length();
    int q=101;
    int pat_hash=0,str_hash=0;
    for(int i=0;pat[i];i++){
        pat_hash+=(pat[i]-'a')%q;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<patL;i++){
        str_hash+=(s[i]-'a')%q;
    }
    if(pat_hash==str_hash){
        if(s.substr(0,patL)==pat)
            return true;
    }
    int x=0;
    for(int i=patL;i<s.length();i++){
        str_hash-=(s[x]-'a')%q;
        str_hash+=(s[i]-'a')%q;
        x++;
        cout<<x<<" "<<i<<endl;
        cout<<s.substr(x,i)<<endl; //When i try to print it is giving the odd results
    }
    return false;

}
bool isRotatedStrOfs1(string s1,string s2){
    string temp=s2+s2;
    return RKalgorithm(s1,temp);
}
int main(){
    string s1,s2;
    cin>>s1>>s2;
    bool res=isRotatedStrOfs1(s1,s2);
    if(res)
        cout<<"Strings are rotations of each other"<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"Strings are not rotations of each other"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

INPUT : aacd     acda

OUPUT :

1 4

cdaa

2 5

daacd   // Why it is giving me the substring with length 5?

3 6

aacda  // Why it is giving me the substring with length 5?

4 7

acda

Strings are not rotations of each other

Can anyone help me ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some explanation of what you are trying to achieve would be... useful.

Comment: `substr()` doesn't take first and last index, as you appear to assume. It takes first index and length. You call `substr(2, 5)` - you get a substring of length 5.

Comment: Sounds like the perfect chance to learn how to use your debugger https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/